# IMG has dimension of 0x0 after added to DOM

Tags: jquery, html, dom, loading, image

I'm adding some HTML code loaded from xml into the dom via jQuery. All browsers do show everything but the included images. Consulting Firebug (or other webdev tools) they show that the image is "naturally" 0px by 0px. Is there any known bug I'm not aware of that I need to call a load method after adding images to the DOM?

EDIT: I tried a lot of different src values. It has nothing to do with the source attribute. I am adding the image to a div that is not visible, even display: none when it gets appended. Can this be the reason? If yes, what do I need to do to trigger the image loading when the div gets visible?

Comment: uhm - what do you mean (quarternion slerp) ?

Comment: have you checked the src atrribute of the img tag?

Comment: yes it says src="img/logo.png".

Comment: fine, make sure that the path of the image is correct and it's loaded as a node element.

Comment: every other img on the page has the same kind of path or url if you like.i'll try absolute path

Comment: Can you set up a test case on http://www.jsfiddle.com ?